# Get unique random rows Laravel Eloquent

Tags: arrays, laravel, session, eloquent, orm

I'm working on a multipage questionnaire, answering and going to the next page I want to get another row from my DB that hasn't been shown yet.

So after generating a random number I store that value into an array, and this array in a session
Next time I'm looking for a random row I retrieve this array to search *except* these values stored in the array

I'll share my code and explain:

```
$x = $this->generateRandInt($request); // random number stored in $x

$this->qs = $request->session()->get('arrayOfQs'); // get the session 

$question = Ctest::find($x['randomInt']); // here I'm simply looking for any random question

// This is the kind of approach I'm lookig for
// $question = Ctest::find($x['randomInt'])->whereNotIn('id', [$this->qs])->get();
// But I get error: Nested arrays may not be passed to whereIn method.

if ($this->qs) {
    array_push($this->qs, $x['randomInt']); // I store the used random into array
    $request->session()->put('arrayOfQs', $this->qs); // I store array into session
    var_dump($this->qs); // array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(8) } 
}else{ // same actions but for the first iteration 
    $qs=[];
    array_push($qs, $x['randomInt']);
    $request->session()->put('arrayOfQs', $qs);
    var_dump($qs); array(3) { [0]=> int(1) } 
}


// This is my function to simply generate a random within a range
public function generateRandInt(Request $request)
{
    $randomInt = mt_rand(1, 20);
    return compact('randomInt');
}
```

What would be the best solution for this situation using Eloquent?

The documentation dictates `whereNotIn('field','array')` should work but I must be missing something...

Why doesn't this work?

```
$question = Ctest::find($x['randomInt'])->whereNotIn('id', [$this->qs])->get();
```

Comment: $this->qs is an array you should pass it not in array

$question = Ctest::find($x['randomInt'])->whereNotIn('id', $this->qs)->get();

Comment: and if you want to get random record by elquent you could do

Ctest::inRandomOrder()->whereNotIn('id',$this->qs)->first();

Comment: OH! I see I just had to remove the extra [ ]. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be something like this you can try

```
$alreadySelected = []
$currentSelected = Ctest::whereNotIn('id', [alreadySelected])->inRandomOrder()->get();
$alreadySelected = array_merge($alreadySelected, $currentSelected->pluk(id)->toArray());
```

Comment: pluck() throws undefined method

Comment: @Koburaq can you please share your code and exact error, because I just tried in tinker in my local, it is working fine.

Comment: check the output of get, if that is giving you collection of eloquent models only then pluck will work.